# C sockets - keeping pool of connections for reuse - s

Tags: c, linux, system

I am writing a two daemon application - a client and a server. It is a very basic version of distributed shell. Clients are connecting to the server, and server issues a command, that is propagated to every client.

I dont know how to create the socket logic on server-side - I do some testing and for now I am accepting connections in an loop and for every incoming connection I fork a child to process the connection

```
while (1) {
   clisockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cliaddr, &clilen);
   if (clisockfd < 0) {
       log_err("err on opening client socket");
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   /* create a new child to process the connection  */
   if((pid = fork()) < 0) {
       log_err("err on forking, something is really broken!");
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   if(!pid) {
       /* here we are in forked process so we dont need the sockfd */
       close(sockfd);
       /* function that handles connection */
       handle_connection(clisockfd);
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   } else {
       close(clisockfd);
   }
 }
```

However what I have now have some disadvantages - I can accept a connection, do something with it, and return to main process (forked process have to return, and then execution in main process is resumed). I would like to keep every socketfd somewhere(a list?) and be able to choose one of those (or all of them) and send to this socketfd a command that I want to issue on my client/s. I assume that I cant do it in traditional accept->fork->return to main process manner.

So it probably should looks like:

client connects -> server set up a new socketfd and saves it somewhere -> drops to shell where I can choose one of socket and send it a command -> somewhere in the whole process it also should wait for next incoming client connections - but where?

If someone could give me an idea what mechanisms should I use to create the logic that I need? Maybe it would be better to issue connection from server to client, not from client to server.

Regards,
Krzysztof

Comment: Use an event loop with `epoll`

Comment: You do know that creating a new process with `fork` really creates a new process that will run in *parallel* with the parent (your main listening) process? So there's no "returning to main process" or "resuming", the main process will simply not stop unless you explicitly tell it to.

Comment: Also, if the connections are unrelated (i.e. the server doesn't need to pass data from one connection to another) I don't see anything wrong with handling it with processes. Can you please elaborate on the problems you have with your current code, what the actual problem you try to solve actually is? (Related reading: ["What is the XY problem"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem))

Comment: Your use case(s) are not quiet clear. From reading "*... server issues a command* I understand: client connects->server issues command->connection gets closed. So why do you want to save/store/reuse any socket?

Answer (score 0):

> I assume that I cant do it in traditional accept->fork->return to main process manner.

You could but it will be hard to design/maintain.

The best solution is to use [`select()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select) (POSIX), [`epoll()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/epoll.7.html) (Linux), [`kqueue()`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=kqueue&sektion=2) (BSD) or [I/O Completion Ports](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365198%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (Windows) depending on your platform.
There is a good examples/explanations about `select()` in [Beej's network programming guide](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html#select).